# why without var?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Difference between using var and not using var in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470488/difference-between-using-var-and-not-using-var-in-javascript)

seems stupid question but just curious.

```
num = "hello";

alert(num);
```

why is this possible I didnt initialize the num variable here.

```
num = "hello";
```

instead of

```
var num = "hello";
```

Comment: Please read some documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var and please search before you ask a new question.

Answer (score 6):

`var` means "Scope this variable to this function" not "Make it possible to use this variable".

If you leave `var` off then it will use the variable in the next scope up from the function. If that scope doesn't have the `var yourVar` then it will keep going up the scope chain until it becomes a global and dangles off the `window` object (assuming a browser or another JS environment in which the default object is `window`).

(This changes in [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Strict_mode), which you are presumably not using.)

Comment: Note that in ECMAScript 5 Strict Mode this kind of assignment is disallowed

Comment: so num="hello" is a variable string with hello string?

Comment: @user1393669: It's not complicated. All that `var` does is changing the scope of the variable. Nothing else. Apart from scope, `num = 5` is equivalent to `var num = 5` (again, in *non*-strict mode). Also have a look at the question I linked to, it contains further information.

Answer (score 1):

Without the `var` keyword the variable is created at the global scope (in browsers under `window`).

If you add the `var` you just assign the variable to the current scope, which in most cases will be a function scope.

In general it will be better to use a function scope in order to not pollute the global scope and prevent conflicts between multiple variables of the same name!